# How to dynamically pass a variable (of string type) value to another variable name in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, dynamic-programming, variable-assignment

I am a former VFP programmer and was amazed by some powerful technics of VFP such as declaring dynamically a variable and assign to it a name from another string variable. I am looking for how to do the same in vb.net. I search but most solutions suggest array or list where I could not use the specific meaningful name of the variables.

I have a list of many variables in a table and for each variable I would like to dynamically declare a variable that have the name of the variable and assign to to it the variable value. Below is just 5 % of the full list

[image]  partial list of the variables

I can declare all the variable one by one but I would prefer a shorter way if any.

How could you assist me?

I have not tried anything.

Comment: Sorry, not an expert of VFP so, your question is a bit unclear to me. Could you add to your question some code examples these "technics" of VFP?

Comment: That's not really how VB works.

Comment: As a former VFP developer, can't say I disagree.  There are many powerful techniques in VFP I've missed.  However, simply vb.net is very structured and doesn't allow the same level of flexablity in those sorts of areas.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. It is finally clear to me that I can't do what I want with vb.net. However from other discussions I will find other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically create variables in a strongly typed language. (You could create a *dynamically typed* variable, but that's not what you're looking for.)

Take a look at the `Dictionary` class, which is a collection of pairs (name and value), like a classic "hash array" or an object in JavaScript.

**Edit**. When you create a dictionary in VB.Net, you specify the datatype of the key (usually a String) and the datatype of the value. If all your values are Integers, yo do something like: `Dim myDict As New Dictionary (Of String, Integer)`. If you really need to store *different classes* of objects (using the same dictionary), you may do: `Dim myDict As New Dictionary (Of String, Object)` (but you'll lose type safety).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer to my question. I will see how to use the dictionary class.